# git bash command equivalent of "node app.js" to connect javascript file to mongodb

Tags: database, windows, mongodb, git-bash

I am currently taking a Udemy course on databases, and have run into an issue. I have set up my git BASH so that the "mongod" and "mongo" commands both work when entered into the shell. I get the "waiting for connections on port 27107" confirmation when running "mongod"

Now, using the instance of the shell where i typed "mongo" The instructor connects a javascript file to the server by typing "node app.js". However, when i type the same command into git bash i get the error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The instructor is running hyper terminal on a mac, whereas I am running git Bash on windows 10. I am confused because all of the commands have been the same up until now.

"node app.js" appears to work when i type it into windows hyper terminal, however none of the other commands work (because i am on windows, and instructor is on mac"

Was wondering if there is possibly a git bash alternative to "node app.js"

Answer (score 1):

So, turns out i was in the mongo shell in gitBash when i was typing "node app.js". When i hit CTRL+C to exit back into node, typing "node app.js" yielded the desired results on gitBash